# no instance of constructor "GLWrapper::GLWrapper" matches the argument list

Tags: c++

I got this two error:
"E0289  no instance of constructor "GLWrapper::GLWrapper" matches the argument list" and
"C2665  'GLWrapper::GLWrapper': no overloaded function could convert all the argument types"

my main code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    GLWrapper* glw = new GLWrapper(1024, 768, "Piano Hammer"); //specify dimensions of window plus title

    printControls(); //print the program controls in the console

    if (!ogl_LoadFunctions()) //if load fails
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ogl_LoadFunctions() failed. Exiting\n"); //inform user of error
        return 0;
    }

    glw->setRenderer(display); //bind display within event loop
    glw->setKeyCallback(keyCallback); //bind display within event loop
    glw->setReshapeCallback(reshape); //bind reshape within event loop

    initialise(glw); //initialise the window

    glw->eventLoop(); //bind the event loop

    delete(glw);
    return 0;
}
```

wrapper_glfw.h

```
#include <string>

/* Inlcude GL_Load and GLFW */
#include <glload/gl_4_0.h>
#include <glload/gl_load.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

class GLWrapper {
private:

    int width;
    int height;
    char *title;
    double fps;
    void(*error_callback)(int error, const char* description);
    void(*renderer)();
    void(*reshape)(GLFWwindow* window, int w, int h);
    void(*keyCallBack)(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods);
    bool running;
    GLFWwindow* window;

public:
    GLWrapper(int width, int height, char *title);
    ~GLWrapper();

    void setFPS(double fps) {
        this->fps = fps;
    }

    /* Callback registering functions */
    void setRenderer(void(*f)());
    void setReshapeCallback(void(*f)(GLFWwindow* window, int w, int h));
    void setKeyCallback(void(*f)(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods));
    void setErrorCallback(void(*f)(int error, const char* description));

    int eventLoop();
    GLFWwindow* getWindow();
};
```

wrapper_glfw.cpp

```
#include "wrapper_glfw.h"

/* Inlcude some standard headers */

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>


/* Constructor for wrapper object */
GLWrapper::GLWrapper(int width, int height, char *title) {

    this->width = width;
    this->height = height;
    this->title = title;
    this->fps = 30;
    this->running = true;

    /* Initialise GLFW and exit if it fails */
    if (!glfwInit()) 
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLFW." << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    setErrorCallback(error_callback);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
#ifdef DEBUG
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_DEBUG_CONTEXT, GL_TRUE);
#endif

    window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, 0, 0);
    if (!window){
        std::cout << "Could not open GLFW window." << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Obtain an OpenGL context and assign to the just opened GLFW window */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* Initialise GLLoad library. You must have obtained a current OpenGL */
    if (!ogl_LoadFunctions())
    {
        std::cerr << "oglLoadFunctions() failed. Exiting" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return;
    }

    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, true);
}


/* Terminate GLFW on destruvtion of the wrapepr object */
GLWrapper::~GLWrapper() {
    glfwTerminate();
}

/* An error callback function to output GLFW errors*/
static void error_callback(int error, const char* description)
{
    fputs(description, stderr);

}

/* Returns the GLFW window handle, required to call GLFW functions outside this class */
GLFWwindow* GLWrapper::getWindow()
{
    return window;
}


/*
GLFW_Main function normally starts the windows system, calls any init routines
and then starts the event loop which runs until the program ends
*/
int GLWrapper::eventLoop()
{
    // Main loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // Call function to draw your graphics
        renderer();

        // Swap buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}


/* Register an error callback function */
void GLWrapper::setErrorCallback(void(*func)(int error, const char* description))
{
    this->error_callback = func;
    glfwSetErrorCallback(func);
}

/* Register a display function that renders in the window */
void GLWrapper::setRenderer(void(*func)()) {
    this->renderer = func;
}

/* Register a callback that runs after the window gets resized */
void GLWrapper::setReshapeCallback(void(*func)(GLFWwindow* window, int w, int h)) {
    reshape = func;
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, reshape);
}


/* Register a callback to respond to keyboard events */
void GLWrapper::setKeyCallback(void(*func)(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods))
{
    keyCallBack = func;
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallBack);
}
```

What I see is nothing wrong..
I don't really know what's wrong with it.

Comment: `"Piano Hammer"` is a `const char*` not a `char*`

Comment: `GLWrapper(int width, int height, char *title);` -- `GLWrapper* glw = new GLWrapper(1024, 768, "Piano Hammer");` -- You are passing a `const char *`, not a `char *`.  Second, why are you not using `std::string`?  If you had done that, the error would not have occurred.  Third: Why are you using `new` to create the object?  It could be simply `GLWrapper glw(1024, 768, "Piano Hammer");`

Answer (score 1):

The constructor is declared as this:

`GLWrapper(int width, int height, char *title);`

However you call it like this:

`GLWrapper* glw = new GLWrapper(1024, 768, "Piano Hammer")`

The third parameter is a `const char *`, not a `char *`, thus the error.  A `char *` means the character buffer is modifiable (i.e. non-const), and a string-literal such as `"Piano Hammer"` is a `const char *` and can't be modified.

---

How to fix the issue?  The simplest thing is to use `std::string` in place of character pointers:

```
class GLWrapper {
private:

    int width;
    int height;
    std::string title;
    //...
    public:
        GLWrapper(int width, int height, std::string title);
    //...
 };
```

and then when you use `title` in functions that require a character pointer, you use the `c_str()` member function.

For example:

`window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title.c_str(), 0, 0);`